# Find and display the max and min values in the array

Tags: python

What is wrong with this program?

```
def find_min(array):
    for counter in range(0,20):
        if nums[counter] < nums[counter]:
            minnum= nums[counter]


def find_max(array):
    for counter in range(0,20):
        if nums[counter] > nums[counter]:
            maxnum= nums[counter]



#main program
nums=[""]*20

nums=[38,56,78,104,34,56,109,374,91,101,56,78,89,982,5,39,43,30,2,85]

minnumber=find_min(nums)

maxnumber=find_max(nums)

print("The smallest number in the array is " , minnumber)

print("The biggest number in the array is " , maxnumber)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and checking? Or reading through it to try and find out the reason? hint: `nums[counter] > nums[counter]`?

Comment: `if nums[counter] < nums[counter]` - when could that be True?

Comment: try adding `print` statements in both those loops to see how the loop progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem in your logic and you have not write any return statement in both of your functions, You can try this solution as per your attemts:

```
def find_min(array):
    minNum = array[0]
    for counter in range(1,len(array)):
        if array[counter] < minNum:
            minNum = array[counter]
    return minNum


def find_max(array):
    maxNum = array[0]
    for counter in range(1,len(array)):
        if array[counter] > maxNum:
            maxNum = array[counter]
    return maxNum

#main program
nums=[""]*20

nums=[38,56,78,104,34,56,109,374,91,101,56,78,89,982,5,39,43,30,2,85]
minnumber=find_min(nums)
maxnumber=find_max(nums)
print("The smallest number in the array is " , minnumber)
print("The biggest number in the array is " , maxnumber)
```

Ouput:

```
The smallest number in the array is  2                                                                                
The biggest number in the array is  982
```

**Other solution:**
If you want to use builtin `min()` or `max()` function it would be easy for you to find minimum and maximum number from a list:

```
def find_min(array):
    return min(array)

def find_max(array):
    return max(array)
```

Both ways gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your functions `find_min()` and `find_max()` are not returning anything. So,`minnumber=find_min(nums)` and `maxnumber=find_max(nums)` are assigned the value `None`.

Secondly, you are passing the global list variable `nums` to both the functions where it is assigned to the parameter `array`. So, there is no point in using the `nums` to refer to the list within the functions. Instead of writing `if nums[counter] < nums[counter]:`, you should write `if array[counter] < array[counter]:`.

Thirdly, you are hard-coding the length of the array in the `range()` function of the `for` loop. This should be avoided.

Finally, you need to read a lot on Python basics.

Since you are a beginner, I am providing you one approach to find the minimum value in a list. There are several other ways by which you can achieve the same result. Try on your own.

**Code**

```py
def find_min(array):
  if len(array) == 0:
    return None
  else:
    minimum = array[0]
    for i in array:
      if i < minimum:
        minimum = i
  return minimum

print(find_min([1, 2, 0, 33, -1])) # -1
```